# How to use OpenVPN GUI for connecting to VPNs with Google Authenticator?

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, gui, google-authenticator

My workplace has a VPN server which requires a Google Auth token to connect. Connecting via console works - I'm asked for the token and the connection goes through smoothly. However connecting via the GUI returns the following error without asking for the token:

```
CHALLENGE: Enter Google Authenticator Code
Enter Google Authenticator Code
MANAGEMENT: Client disconnected
ERROR: could not read static challenge response from stdin
```

How do I force OpenVPN to request the token rather than shutting down the connection?

I'm using OpenVPN v2.3 x64 on Windows 10.

Comment: VPN to connect Google is Block, look a terms official google security. VPN mean proxy.

Comment: @rany Latest (v10) from openvpn.net

Comment: @rany are there other GUI clients for OpenVPN?

Comment: @rany the GUI itself is version 10. The OpenVPN is version 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible in the current version of OpenVPN GUI. Use the console version to get it working.